# How to parse unknown JSON objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm trying to figure out how I would parse the following information:

```
{
  'unknown-value': {
    name: 'AB',
    id: 'BLUE'
  },
  'unknown-value': {
    name: 'AC',
    id: 'PURPLE'
  }
}
```

Wanting to parse them then create an array of values like these:

```
names = ['AB', 'AC']
ids = ['BLUE', 'PURPLE']
```

Haven't come across something like this where it isn't an array of objects so I'm a little stumped on what to do.

Comment: have you tried [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can iterate through your array of objects with **forEach**
- Then get the **values** of the object with `Object.values()`.
- You can go then with **forEach** over these values and push it into the dedicated array names or ids in this case.

```js
   
const obj = [{
  'unknown-value': {
    name: 'AB',
    id: 'BLUE'
  },
  'unknown-value2': {
    name: 'AC',
    id: 'PURPLE'
  }
}]

let names = [];
let ids = [];

obj.forEach((x) => { 
Object.values(x).forEach((y)=>{
  names.push(y.name);
  ids.push(y.id);
 })
})

console.log(names);
console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need that unknown key as well, so Object.entries is your friend:

```
const normalized = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({key, ...value}));
```

Now normalized contains an array of objects each with a new property "key" which contains the key.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { names, ids, } = Object.values({

  'foo': {
    name: 'AB',
    id: 'BLUE',
  },
  'bar': {
    name: 'AC',
    id: 'PURPLE',
  }
}).reduce((map, item) => {

  map.names.push(item.name)
  map.ids.push(item.id)

  return map;

}, { names: [], ids: [] });

console.log('names :', names);
console.log('ids :', ids);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it can get, try this approach and you will find the desired result

```
object = {
  'unknown-value': {
    name: 'AB',
    id: 'BLUE'
  },
  'unknown-value': {
    name: 'AC',
    id: 'PURPLE'
  }
};

names = [];
ids = [];

for (key in object) {
    names.push(object[key].name);
    ids.push(object[key].id);        
}

for (value of names) {
    console.log(value);
}

for (value of ids) {
    console.log(value);
}
```